# PHP Query with result echoed shows blank

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working with a app using Google Cloud Messaging and Facebook, I'm saving the GCM-device ID (Google Cloud Messaging device ID) and FacebookId in a mySQL database. The saving works just fine, but when I send the facebookId I want the `gcm_id` to be returned. The `echo $row['gcm_id']` is not showing me the result, I've checked so all credentials are correct and the facebookId we are sending is correct to the one in the database. Do someone knows what's wrong in this PHP code?

```
function showID($con, $facebookId){
    $id = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `gcm_id` FROM `android_users` WHERE `facebookId` =  $facebookId");
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($id))
    {
        echo $row['gcm_id'];
        $deviceId = $row['gcm_id'];
    }
        //push($deviceId);
}
```

Comment: Try once
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `gcm_id` FROM `android_users` WHERE `facebookId` =  $facebookId") or die('Can't execute');

or just echo "Hi"; in the loop so that it can be verified that control is coming in the loop or not?

Comment: Have you been able to confirm -- without a doubt -- that your loop gets executed at least once? E.g replace with `echo 'gcm_id : ' . $row['gcm_id'];`

Comment: @PrateekShukla I'm still getting an empty response

Comment: @RandomSeed I know that the echo I'm using now will work because it have. I think the problem is in the query

Comment: Try This query-

"SELECT `gcm_id` FROM `android_users` WHERE `facebookId` =  '$facebookId'"

Comment: @PrateekShukla, It works, make it to an answer so I can accept it ;) Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This query- `"SELECT gcm_id FROM android_users WHERE facebookId = '$facebookId'"`